# Counterexample: surjective module homomorphism in an exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

I need to give an example to show that the exactness of $0 \to M_1 \to M_2 \to M_3 \to 0$ need not imply that the map $\operatorname{Hom}_R(N,M_2) \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(N,M_3)$ is surjective, where the latter is defined as $h \mapsto g \circ h$. I really suck at coming up with counter-examples; I don't even know where to start. I have tried the exact sequence: 
$$
0 \to 2\mathbf{Z} \to \mathbf{Z} \to \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z} \to 0, 
$$
over the ring $R = \mathbf{Z}$. However, it seems to be true that every element in $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbf{Z}(\mathbf{Z},\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})$ can be written as a composition of an $R$-homomorphism $\mathbf{Z} \to \mathbf{Z}$ and the projection map. Does someone have some suggestions for counterexamples? I don't have any toolbox of counterexamples available yet in this subject, so I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $\text{Hom}(N, -)$ is a left exact functor for any $N$. The problem you're encountering in constructing counter-examples is that $\text{Hom}_R(N, -)$ is right exact precisely when $N$ is a projective $R$-module.  In your case, choosing $N = \mathbb{Z}$ was not going to get you anywhere, because $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}, -)$ is exact.

However, you are very close to a good counterexample. Try taking $N = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ instead (note $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is not even flat as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module).

Now, can you compute $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: You are right thanks! I can't follow everything in your explanation, but taking $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $N = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Then taking $id \in Hom_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ works right? Since $Hom_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ contains only the zero homomorphism.

Comment: Yes that is exactly right! Sorry if the point about projective modules was inappropriate here. At some point when you learn about derived functors (and $\text{Ext}$) you will have a lot to say about this question.

Comment: Yeah it's good to have a preview of some of the even nicer things to come!